# Bad Authentication Data?

Tags: ruby, twitter

Using the 'twitter' gem:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ENV['TWITTER_KEY'],
  config.consumer_secret = ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
end

twitter = Twitter::Client.new(
  oauth_token: current_user.twitter_token,
  oauth_token_secret: current_user.twitter_secret
)
```

and getting a

```
Twitter::Error::Unauthorized: Could not authenticate you
```

when trying to call

```
twitter.user_timeline('saiko_chriskun')
```

The keys should be fine since they run through omniauth ok and I'm able to fetch the user's oauth_token and secret.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

http://sferik.github.com/twitter/